# In Android Jetpack compose how to achieve GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.....?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I want to observe onFling Function to detect Velocityx and Velocity Means Swiping force/Velocity. In android we attach this to the android view.But donot find a way how to call this in Jetpack compose or alternative function for this in jetpack compose...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please take the [Animation-in-Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-animation) codelab to understand better, but for now, here's how you can achieve something similar

```
private fun Modifier.swipeToDismiss(
    onDismissed: () -> Unit
): Modifier = composed {
    // This `Animatable` stores the horizontal offset for the element.
    val offsetX = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    pointerInput(Unit) {
        // Used to calculate a settling position of a fling animation.
        val decay = splineBasedDecay<Float>(this)
        // Wrap in a coroutine scope to use suspend functions for touch events and animation.
        coroutineScope {
            while (true) {
                // Wait for a touch down event.
                val pointerId = awaitPointerEventScope { awaitFirstDown().id }
                // Interrupt any ongoing animation.
                offsetX.stop()
                // Prepare for drag events and record velocity of a fling.
                val velocityTracker = VelocityTracker()
                // Wait for drag events.
                awaitPointerEventScope {
                    horizontalDrag(pointerId) { change ->
                        // Record the position after offset
                        val horizontalDragOffset = offsetX.value + change.positionChange().x
                        launch {
                            // Overwrite the `Animatable` value while the element is dragged.
                            offsetX.snapTo(horizontalDragOffset)
                        }
                        // Record the velocity of the drag.
                        velocityTracker.addPosition(change.uptimeMillis, change.position)
                        // Consume the gesture event, not passed to external
                        change.consumePositionChange()
                    }
                }
                // Dragging finished. Calculate the velocity of the fling.
                val velocity = velocityTracker.calculateVelocity().x
                // Calculate where the element eventually settles after the fling animation.
                val targetOffsetX = decay.calculateTargetValue(offsetX.value, velocity)
                // The animation should end as soon as it reaches these bounds.
                offsetX.updateBounds(
                    lowerBound = -size.width.toFloat(),
                    upperBound = size.width.toFloat()
                )
                launch {
                    if (targetOffsetX.absoluteValue <= size.width) {
                        // Not enough velocity; Slide back to the default position.
                        offsetX.animateTo(targetValue = 0f, initialVelocity = velocity)
                    } else {
                        // Enough velocity to slide away the element to the edge.
                        offsetX.animateDecay(velocity, decay)
                        // The element was swiped away.
                        onDismissed()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        // Apply the horizontal offset to the element.
        .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
}
```

I would not recommend trying to comprehend this code just from here, you should probably refer to the documentation at hand, while taking the codelab as well. This implements a swipe-to-dismiss functionality on a simple list item in a compose-sample app, the code to which you will find linked to in the start of the codelab. Here are [all the sample apps](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) published for compose, for your reference.

Comment: Thanks i have tried this code and after some modifications i got the expected Result